# Multiparty video conferencing between Linux/Windows?

Tags: video, voip, crossplatform

I have a group of friends that we are often physically separate, but we like to play old school table top RPG's.  A video conferencing solution seems ideal for this.

What we need is cross platform, video (everyone sees everyone), sound (everyone hears everyone), desktop sharing (everyone see's at least one, maybe all), and possibly whiteboard (everyone sees & can draw).

I have a server running already, so I'm up to installing something centralized.  Although P2P might be easier over all.

I found BigBlueButton.  Sounds like a wonderful idea, but they built that software around the idea that it was the only thing on the server. Grrrrr It's the only thing I've found that I can NOT get to install on Ubuntu 12.04.  And I don't want to play around with running it as a VM.  Not sure my machine will handle it well as it's just on spec for BBB w/o being VM'd.

So, if anyone has suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have found a solution that works for us, although I haven't tested it under linux (should work tho).

This solution is specific to table top RPG's, but could be used for other purposes as well.

It's a website called roll20.net

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 4):

Google Hangouts work fairly well for me for video-conferencing a group on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing free that I am aware of.

You can do everything you want with Skype Pro for $9/month, and they have clients for every platform including Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I should have included that several of the players are college students, so a monthly sub isn't a good idea.  :)

Comment: Yeah - the state of multiparty videoconferencing isn't great yet unfortunately.